# How to remove all html tags from textarea if textarea is dynamic?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#temp').val(function(i,val) {
            return $('<div>').html(val).text();
        });
    });
</script>
<textarea  id="temp"><?php echo $fetch['description']; ?></textarea>
```

In this code I have a textarea where I am fetching its value from database. Now, In my database table column it have text with multiple tags like tag P,ul,br and more. So, How can I remove these tags from textarea ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: if you want to do it in php, have you tried striptags yet?

Comment: Can you share some input and output samples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the PHP function [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) for that:

```
<textarea  id="temp"><?php echo strip_tags($fetch['description']); ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic function with general syntax is below plz try with this function
string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags] )